# Alternative to printing a list in a text box?

Tags: java

Hi i'm using a GUI and at the moment printing a list to console. I understand you can print strings with text boxes using `textBox.setText("")` but instead of printing my list to console I want to use a text box or any other alternative.

At the moment ive got this as my printlist method:

```
private void printList(){
    System.out.println(myList);
}
```

After attempting to do:

```
System.out.println(resultsBox.setText(myList));
```

I realize, this will not work as it only works with strings not lists. So yeah, what else could I use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `toString()` ie: `myList.toString()`

Comment: It will not work because it needs a String, and a List is way too different. You can either use `toString()`, or create your own method/class that exports the list to a String.

Comment: I wrote this but it is still not working. Am i doing something wrong?
                myList.toString();
  System.out.println(resultsBox.setText(myList));

Comment: oh my boy! its like this `System.out.println(resultsBox.setText(myList.toString()));`

Comment: Please notice `System.out.println` will output nothing or throw an error or anything since  setText returns nothing (void).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, got it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to convert your list to a `String`,

```
if(myList!=null) {
    resultsBox.setText(myList.toString());
}
```

and if there's a valid `getText()`, you can test the value that you set by printing it,

`System.out.println(resultsBox.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call

```
resultsBox.setText(myList)
```

separately.

Notice that this is a method call by itself that sets the values in the box. It does not return a value so you cannot pass it as an argument to println().

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately doing that gives me the same error as trying to print it.

The method setText(String) in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)

Comment: You need to use `myList.toString()` for this to compile.